# What's the (Dutch) name of this "push your luck" dice game?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

My wife and her family introduced a game to me that they know (in Dutch) as "knobbelen". It seems similar to the game of [5000s](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/5000en)<sup>*(in Dutch)*</sup>.

In this game, each player throws three dice (d6) repeatedly, either until the current throw doesn't score or the player has their cumulative throws scored.

The dice score as follows:

- 3 equal dice scores 1000
- 1, 2, 3 scores 500
- if not one of the above, every 5 is worth 50 and every 1 is worth 100

A running total is kept during each player's turn. Once that has reached 300, the player can choose to end their turn, scoring that total. But they are encouraged to keep on throwing, pushing their luck. If a throw doesn't score, the running total is lost and their turn ends.

Is this game known under another name than "knobbelen"? Especially since *knobbelen* is more commonly the Dutch name for [the game of Spoof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoof_(game)).

Comment: This sounds like one of the many variants of [Farkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkle). (Not posting as an answer because I know nothing about Dutch versions/names.)

Comment: @BenjaminCosman it sure looks like it, thanks. Seems like the game of 5000s I mentioned is _a_ farkle variant as well.

Comment: If I look for the game on boardgamegeek it gives me the following game: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/11456/zilch